# K.K. Slider Songs

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've been trying to get certain songs to complete my song list. but I've noticed the Nookling's store hasn't really been randomizing their song choices to buy. Do the Nookling's only put out a few songs and the rest I have to get from K.K. himself?

Answer (score 1):

The songs that appear in the Nookings' store are randomized completely. Even if they may seem to be a bit consecutive, all of the songs are randomized. If you're pretty desperate to get a certain song, just keep checking back. Your best bet is to wait for Saturday to roll around.